# Retuning Inception Models with retrain.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've converted the inception_v3 and inception_resnet_v2 .ckpt files found at
https://research.googleblog.com/2016/08/improving-inception-and-image.html
to a frozen .pb file and i'm trying to use it with the tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining.py. Specifically there's this part:

```
BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_NAME = 'pool_3/_reshape:0'
BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE = 2048
MODEL_INPUT_WIDTH = 299
MODEL_INPUT_HEIGHT = 299
MODEL_INPUT_DEPTH = 3
JPEG_DATA_TENSOR_NAME = 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'
RESIZED_INPUT_TENSOR_NAME = 'ResizeBilinear:0'
MAX_NUM_IMAGES_PER_CLASS = 2 ** 27 - 1  # ~134M
```

I can't figure out how to adapt this for the new inception v3 names or inception resnet v2. I've looked at the graph in tensorboard but it didn't help. What would the pool_3 layer become? Whats the size? And what about ResizeBilinear?

For inception_resnet_v2 it looks like it should be Logits/Flatten/Reshape or just Logits with size 1536 but it says those aren't in the graph.

This retraining is orders of magnitude faster than the TF slim alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I used DATA_URL = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v4_2016_09_09.tar.gz'.

And then I did not have to change anything else. It is working properly.
Let me know if you face any problems.

It works with http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz as well.

Answer (score 0):

these values should work:

```
bottleneck_tensor_name = 'InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Flatten/Reshape:0'
bottleneck_tensor_size = 1536
resized_input_tensor_name = 'InputImage:0'
```